# Unable to right click and select a value using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to right click using selenium webdriver. When I right click on the date highlighted in red,I will have a menu opened from where I have to select "Show CTR Impressions Label".

[image]

I am able to right click and select "Show Impressions Label" but unable to click it.

Here is my code:

```
string xpath = "//div[@class='highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels']/span[2]/div";
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
System.out.println("date="+element.getText());
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).contextClick(element).build().perform();
action
  .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
  .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
  .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
  .build().perform();
```

Kindly suggest.Also, how can I select "Show Impressions Label" based on the text and not the arrow keys?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is this a public page? could you provide the url?

Comment: did you tried move to element with coordinates instead of keys?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution Only , Based on my previous observations :: You are doing it in 2 lines. Combine this and you should be able to do so. Second perform takes focus away from element. And thus the continuity is broken.

```
action.moveToElement(element).contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```